# How do the impermeabilization of external power cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, rain

Hypothetical situation: I would have to install some external reflectors like this on my store.

[image: reflector]

It should be screwed as higher as possible on the external wall to illuminate outdoors, increase store light, etc.

There is no raceway on the rooftop. How I proceed to make the impermeabilization of the power cables?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Exact answer will vary depending on location. What country are you in?

Comment: Yes, where are you on this planet?

Comment: Why? What country are you?

Comment: I am nearer of the amazon rainforest. American continent indeed.

Comment: Electrical requirements ("code") varies by country (and sometimes more than that - in the US it often varies by state or even city/county). Plus the available and/or customary materials for various purposes varies considerably around the world. What is normal for US/Canada may be totally wrong for Brazil, and vice versa. (And if you are in the Philippines, all bets are off!)

Comment: Hypothetical situation?  Have you researched "how  exterior electric fixtures are wired to be  weather proof"?  For actual (*non hypothetical*) applications in the USA  see -  https://www.thespruce.com/nec-outdoor-electrical-wiring-tips-1152274

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact 2 Codidact I know. I just wanted to see what is the possible solution did in your country, USA. The answer no need to be directed to my country.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Good read. I will take a look.

Comment: In the US, the answer is to use THWN wire, which is rated for use in wet locations, run through conduit (which is assumed, when outside, to fill up with water). There are ways to minimize water (e.g., weep holes to let water drain out of each box) but there is an assumption that if it can get wet, it will.

Comment: Interesting. Your answer is what I was looking for. This can get best answer reward for this question.
Besides, I apologize. Was to me explicity write in the title "how is it did In USA country". Next, I will to hit it.

Comment: "how is it done... ***

Comment: @Guilherme -- so, Brazil then?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes dear, but it doesnt matter cuz i would like to get how is it made, in general, in United States

Comment: Besides NEC are very similar to NBR5410 of Brazil.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the help center.